# Format number of minutes into a Duration of HH:MM?

Tags: google-sheets, format, duration

I have a column that produces a fractional number of minutes, e.g.

```
71.5
```

I would like another column to format that into a Duration of the form HH:MM, rounding up minutes, i.e.

```
1:12
```

Or

```
1h 12m
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
=roundup(A1,0)/1440
```

and format:

```
[h]:mm
```

Comment: ah, where 1440 is the number of minutes in a day. So this converts to days and then formats. Nice!

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it works...although why roundup? I just used round and it seems to round up/down correctly. For bonus points, how would I format it as 2h 3m?

Comment: Your question said "rounding up minutes" not rounding minutes. Now granted that had a .5 on it, but it was hard to know what you meant. That is why I gave both ROUND and CEILING based answers. I'm thinking about the bonus (though my method already does that, I cannot argue that this one is not more elegant -- it uses more of the spreadsheet's built-in power and less math).

Comment: [h] " h "m" m" will give the bonus, remove the spaces before h and m if you wish.

Comment: OK I think I have it the way I want now, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

=round(divide(A1-mod (A1,60),60)) & " h " & round(mod (A1,60)) & " m"

would do it with rounding 11.5 minutes up but 11.25 down. I will think about what if even that should say 12.

EDIT: There is a subtle case the above misses on. IT says 179.5 is 2 hours and 60 minutes.

Better is

`=round(divide(round(A1)-mod (round(A1),60),60)) & " h " & (mod (round(A1),60)) & " m"`

The first round should not be needed, but I want no floating point madness.

If you really want 71.25 to say 1 hr 12 minutes, go with

`=round(divide(ceiling(A1)-mod (ceiling(A1),60),60)) & " h " & (mod (CEILING(A1),60)) & " m"`